# pwm problem in mikroC -pic-

Tags: pic

i am trying to do an simple PWM example in mikroC program using ISIS simulator for pic16f877a and i used the code in the program help and it didnt work

```
for(;;)
{
    Pwm_Init(5000);
    pwm_start();
    delay_ms(500);
}
```

Comment: There is too little to go on here - is this the whole of your code? How didn't it work? What is the error message?

Comment: "Didn't work" is a useless description.

Comment: i think this the code used to start the pwm in mikroC i want to use pwm in a project but first i need to see how it works first and make sure that it works

Comment: it "didnt work" there is no errors in compiling but the problem that it do not work in the simulation ....i am sorry for being not clear in my question ..:)

Answer (score 2):

PWM needs at least 2 parameters. You only supply the 5000, which will probably be the frequency, but what about the duty cycle? If you don't initialize that and it defaults to 0 or 100 %, then you won't see anything.

**edit**
[It appears](http://www.shibuvarkala.com/2009/02/pulse-width-modulation-or-pwm-tutorial.html) you have to call the function `Pwm_Change_Duty()` with a value between 0 (minimum) and 255 (maximum) to set the duty cycle.
*end of edit*

Most microcontrollers with PWM will have more than 1 PWM channel, so you'll have to tell the program which channel you want to use as well.

Also, I don't know what Pwm_Init() and Pwm_start() do exactly, but normally they should be outside your main loop. Now you're executing them again and again. IMO should be

```
Pwm_Init(5000);  
pwm_start();  
for(;;)
{ 
  delay_ms(500); 
},
```

and then the delay() serves no function, so that you can omit it:

```
Pwm_Init(5000);   
pwm_start(); 
for(;;)
{ 
}.
```

Comment: ok i am just asking.... this is the code i saw in the help i used the code pwm_change_duty(value) and it didnt work so i think there is another thing to do so the pwm work on the ISIS

Comment: @alone - but have tried the `Pwm_Change_Duty()` I mention in my answer? And you also haven't answered Oli's question: what does "doesn't work" mean? What do you observe? If you can add details to the question it may be reopened.

Comment: of course .... the code compile very will and there is no error in compiling but in the simulation it do not work thats my problem